# Prepared statements with MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am having some trouble with, what I believe to by syntax, for prepared statements.

I have the following code

```
String query2="SELECT lname FROM school_student WHERE sid = ? ORDER BY sid;";

PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement(query2);
ps.setInt(1, 3);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(query2);
```

The problem I am having is that I am getting this error message:

> `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? ORDER BY sid' at line 1`

However, when I substitute the "?" in my query for a 3, the query works fine with no error and gives me what I want.  There seems to be something wrong with how I am setting the value of the "?" in my query?  Am I using the wrong syntax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use

```
ps.executeQuery();
```

(i.e. use the overloaded `executeQuery()` method which doesn't take any argument). You already passed the query when preparing the statement.

Comment: `ps.executeQuery()` in his example.

Comment: You should stress the fact that this is the overloaded version. It took me several seconds to understand what you are saying :)

Comment: Just to note, that ending semicolon (;) also shouldn't be in the query. The MySQL driver apparently allows it, but other DBMSes may not.

Comment: @JBNizet- why does it mySQL reports error in the query?? It is confusing to know where are we going wrong with that error ,btw I had same problem which was resolved by this answer thanx

Comment: @Creator because you ask the statement to execute a query containing question marks, and that is not a valid SQL query. Whe using executeQuery(sql), the SQL is executed as is.

Answer (score 2):

use this query :-

> String query2 = "SELECT lname FROM school_student WHERE sid =
>   "+attribute+" ORDER BY sid;";

and simply use

> ps.executeQuery();

Answer (score -1):

I think their is syntax problem while preparing query
try this one...
String query2="SELECT lname FROM school_student WHERE sid = +variablename+ ORDER BY sid;"